# Misspelled WWW in Wordpress settings

Tags: wordpress

wanted to set my website from http://something.com to http://www.something.com in Wordpress settings, but I misspelled WWW and now it is WWWW and whole website isn't working.

how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you can't access the administration panel you'll need to access your database directly and update it there.

Comment: yep,you're right. I cannot access to admin menu at all. Where and what sould I change in database? thanks

Comment: In database you will find a table yourprefix_options .. Update your settings in siteurl and home rows there. It should work fine then.

Comment: Thanks, It works now !!

Answer (score 0):

You should access your database (probably your host provides a phpMyAdmin —check your control panel— or use some SQL client like HeidiSQL or SequelPro) and look for the rows `siteurl` and `home` in the `option_name` field of `wp_options` table (assuming your table prefix is `wp_`, which is the default).